# Docker Compose: Cannot connect to Redis

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

I'm following the Docker Compose tutorial here 
https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part5/#recap-optional

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: example/get-started:part-1
    deploy:
      replicas: 10
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports: 
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - webnet
  visualizer:
    image: dockersamples/visualizer:stable
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    networks:
      - webnet
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    networks:
      - webnet
  driver:
    build: .
    links:
      - redis
networks:
  webnet:
```

and while Redis seems to be running on myvm1, the app is unable to connect to it, and gives an error.

This is the app code in case it matters:

```
from flask import Flask
from redis import Redis, RedisError
import os
import socket

redis = Redis(host="redis", db=0, socket_connect_timeout=0, socket_timeout=0)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
  try:
    visits = redis.incr("counter")
  except RedisError:
    visits = "<i>cannot connect to redis. Counter disabled</i>"

  html = "<h3>Hello {name}!</h3>" \
         "<b>Hostname:</b> {hostname}<br/>" \
         "<b>Visits:</b> {visits}"
  return html.format(name=os.getenv("NAME", "World"), hostname=socket.gethostname(), visits=visits)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

VM IPs:

> myvm1     -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.101:2376
>   v17.07.0-ce
>
> myvm2     -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.102:2376
>   v17.07.0-ce

Redis is running without errors on VM.

Any idea? There are many similar discussions online, but none helped yet.

Comment: Can you connect to the running redis using netcat or telnet on port 6379?

Comment: Is your `driver` container the application code that should be linked to redis?

Comment: @WillBarnwell Yes it does on 0.0.0.0

Comment: @AndrewGraham-Yooll yes

Answer (score 1):

If the redis is running on the VM , the binding might not be proper . Can you please check if its binding on 0.0.0.0 or else you need to edit the redis 
config to bind on 0.0.0.0 and port for external service to connect to it

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. This is what it shows *:6379->6379/tcp. Is that correct? If I need to edit the redis config, can you please list the path for it?

Comment: it will be in redis.conf  look for entry `bind 127.0.0.1` and change it to `bind 0.0.0.0`

Comment: thanks a lot. Alas it's still not working. I will update if I reach a solution